# Display Flex on parent not applying to all children images and text

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent element that contains text and images. I would like to use display flex to adjust the width of images to be relative to the number of them. I would like the text to stay full width of the parent, so effectively skipping the inside text and only using flex for image.

```css
.project-body p {
  width: 100%!important;
}

.project-body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-body">
    <p>
       Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80">
    <p>
       Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80">
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `.project-body p ` to also be `display: flex;` (and not necessarily also `width: 100%!important;`)?

Comment: flex-wrap:wrap on the flexbox container